# How pass the arguments to sub-template when using STRawGroupDir

Tags: java, stringtemplate

I am using StringTemplate v4.05 to build my web application. 
As I am using `STRawGroupDir`, I do not define something like `init(v) :: ...` in each .st

Currently I can successfully render the sub-template like below:
('$' is my delimiter )

```
$/elements/test()$
```

But when test.st is like below

```
<div>Hello $name$</div>
```

I do not know how to pass the argument to $name$. 
My target is like below

```
$/elements/test(["Cavid"])$
$/elements/test(["Daniel"])$
$/elements/test(["Candy"])$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `STRawGroupDir` and template has only one placeholder, it can be referred to as `it`.

In your case test.st would be

```
<div>Hello $it$</div>
```